# quickly take all correlated rows from the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large table with multiple columns representing linked events. This includes columns `id` and `nextId`, where `id` means id of some event1, and `nextId` suggest in which another event this event1 was used. However, there is no column '`prev_id`' which would say which event0 contributed to event1. Is it possible to build a query which will generate for me such a table without taking a very long running time?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
id | nextId
10 |  34
5  | 67
22 | 23
2  | 10
16 | 22
4  | 5
```

What I want to have is the following:

```
prev_id | id | next_id
2       | 10 | 34
4       | 5  | 67
16      | 22 | 23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join`:

```
select t.id as prev_id, t.nextid as id, tnext.nextid as next_id
from t join
     t tnext
     on tnext.id = t.nextid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need a self join.

But for the sake of readability, I would recommend using a CTE:

```
with prevs as (
    select nextid as id, id as previd from ids
)
select previd, id, nextid
from ids
join prevs using(id)
;
 previd | id | nextid 
--------+----+--------
      4 |  5 |     67
      2 | 10 |     34
     16 | 22 |     23
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, you can also accomplish this using hierarchical queries.

```
WITH test_data AS (
    SELECT 10 AS ID,34 AS nextID FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 5,67 FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 22,23 FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 2,10 FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 16,22 FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 4,5 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT h.*
FROM (
    SELECT PRIOR t.ID AS prevID,
           t.ID,
           t.nextID
    FROM test_data t
    CONNECT BY t.ID = PRIOR t.nextID
) h
WHERE h.prevID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY h.prevID
```